# Notification/Service - Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

In my app I start a foreground service and create a notification for it:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
...
builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.icon));
...
```

This throws an exception on one of my users devices like below (a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.` exception).

My icons do have default dimensions and small sizes, don't know why they make problems on one device.

Does anyone know what the real issue could be? And how I could avoid this issue or gracefully handle this case? Seems to be a memory issue.

**Mipmap icon**

I have included following icons:

- mdpi (48x48, 3,51kB)
- hdpi (72x72, 6,65kB)
- xhdpi (96x96, 9,08kB)
- xxhdpi (144x144, 17,2kB)
- xxxhdpi (192x192, 22,0kB)

**Exception**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.my.app.services.OverlayService@ea0edcc with Intent { act=RESUME cmp=com.my.app/.services.OverlayService }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeWriteToParcel(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.writeToParcel(Bitmap.java:1541)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.writeToParcel(Icon.java:705)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1437)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1343)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
    at android.app.Notification.writeToParcel(Notification.java:1731)
    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:701)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:230)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:194)
    at com.my.app.services.BaseOverlayService.a(SourceFile:39)
    at com.my.app.services.BaseOverlayService.a(SourceFile:23)
    at com.my.app.services.OverlayService.onStartCommand(SourceFile:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3062)
```

Comment: I meet the same crash as you. Have you resolved this problem? I find this article analyze this Runtime Exception but I dont find the way solve it. https://blog.csdn.net/u013989732/article/details/78456276 Sorry it's not in English.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors. It also happens when I start a foreground service with a notification. No solution yet.

Comment: Any luck fixing this?

Comment: I am also getting this now

Comment: Have you tried compressing the bitmap? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12908133/1221011